# Does Superior Will work on Unnatural Vitality?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats

**Superior Will:** *If you are dazed or stunned, you can make a saving throw at the start of your turn to end that effect, even if the effect doesn’t normally end on a save.*

**Unnatural Vitality:** *When you drop to 0 hit points or fewer and are subjected to the dying condition, you can choose to be dazed, instead of falling unconscious. You make death saving throws as normal, and if you fail one, you fall unconscious instead of being dazed.*

Can a revenant use the SW feature to get rid of the daze effect from UV? Normally I'd say yes, since the daze effect certainly is one that "doesn't normally end on a save", but in this case you'd still be below 0 hp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this to get over being dazed, but you will still need to make the death saving throws every round and will still die at minus your bloodied value. Nice combo!

Comment: Yeah, I only see 2 possible readings here, either dazed is cleared until you fall unconscious, or you fall unconscious when you clear the dazed, and the more I read up, the more I'm buying this ruling. Worth mentioning that this ruling is supported by the [Revenant handbook](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2699416)

Comment: @Ravn It's self-explanatory. This combination of powers would allow you to remain below 0hp without suffering the effects of being dazed (1 action per round). What more can be said?

Comment: I guess you're right. Having read a four page discussion (with no real conclusion) on the issue, I assumed it would be more controversial.

Comment: @waxeagle According to the guide, "you are only dazed when you are "subject to the dying condition"." The way I saw it, you're subject to the dying condition as long as you're below 0hp.

Comment: @Ravn See the next line "So once you clear daze, your stay that way till you get healed and drop below 0 again." Then it goes on to suggest SW as a way to clear the daze